# LINQ to XML : A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone guide me on to repairing the error on this query :

```
       var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("VHost") 
                          where(from x in item.Descendants("Application"))
                          select new clsApplication
                       {
                           ConnectionsTotal = item.Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
                       };
```

It displays a compiler error "A query body must end with a select clause or a group clause". Where am I going wrong?

Would appreciate any help..

Thanks.

Edit : Here is my XML(haven't closed the tags here)...I need the connectioncount values inside the Application..

```
    - <Server>
  <ConnectionsCurrent>67</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>1424182</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>1385091</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>39091</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>410455.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>540146.0</MessagesOutBytesRate> 
- <VHost>
  <Name>_defaultVHost_</Name> 
  <TimeRunning>5129615.178</TimeRunning> 
  <ConnectionsLimit>0</ConnectionsLimit> 
  <ConnectionsCurrent>67</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>1424182</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>1385091</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>39091</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>410455.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>540146.0</MessagesOutBytesRate> 
- <Application>
  <Name>TestApp</Name> 
  <Status>loaded</Status> 
  <TimeRunning>411642.953</TimeRunning> 
  <ConnectionsCurrent>11</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>43777</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>43135</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>642</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>27876.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>175053.0</MessagesOutBytesRate>
```

Comment: Your `where` clause is incorrect. What are you trying to filter out?

Comment: Trying to get ConnectionsTotal...just edited it and made it clear. ConnectionsTotal is an element inside Application

Comment: and ConnectionsTotal is an element inside Application, which is inside VHost yeah?

Comment: exactly...see my edits..

Comment: see my answer, it's easier than you think :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about this part

```
from x in item.Descendants("Application")
```

inside your `Where` clause. You should change it so that

- there is a `select` clause at the end, and
- it makes up an expression that evaluates to `true` for `item` objects that you would like to keep.

Here is my best guess at what you are trying to do (**EDIT :** attempt number two)

```
var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("VHost").Descendants("Application") 
              select new clsApplication {
                  ConnectionsTotal = item.Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
              };
```

Comment: foreach (var obj in objApps)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(obj.ConnectionsTotal);

Comment: using your code plus above displays the ConnectionsTotal inside VHost and not Application..I need to use the ConnectionsTotal inside Application

Comment: Attempt number two is perfect...but do you have any ideas to avoid .Descendants.Decendants coming repeatedly?

Comment: @Josh It looks like in your case it would be OK to drop the `.Descendants("VHost")` part, because using `xDoc.Descendants("Application")` would give you the same result.

Answer (score 3):

The error is complaining about your inner from clause (inside the where) it looks like you're trying to do a select many (unintentional clippy reference).

```
var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("VHost") 
              from x in item.Descendants("Application")
              select new clsApplication
                       {
                           ConnectionsTotal = x.Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
                       };
```

Comment: displays connectionstotal that's within the VHost..can we get the value of connectionstotal that is within application?

Comment: This query will give a clsApplication for every instance of Application within every instance of Vhost. The ConnectionsTotal is the total for each application.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing select in query within where clause, you can change it something like

```
var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("VHost") 
                     where(item.Descendants("Application").Any())
                     select new clsApplication
                     {
                           ConnectionsTotal = item.Element("Application").Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
                     };
```

Comment: that displays another error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'bool'

Comment: I haven't declared any bool for that error to show up..any ideas why its throwing that?

Comment: can we avoid using .Element .Element repeatedly?

Answer (score 2):

Simply do the following, no need for the `where` clause. Descendants will search children at **ALL** levels, not just immediately below:

```
var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("Application") 
                   select new clsApplication
                   {
                       ConnectionsTotal = item.Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
                   };
```

Answer (score 1):

This may help:

```
        var objApps = from item in xDoc.Descendants("VHost")
                       from x in item.Descendants("Application")
                      select new clsApplication
                   {
                       ConnectionsTotal = item.Element("Application").Element("ConnectionsTotal").Value
                   };
```

Answer (score 1):

I like the procedural way of linq which can be more linear in its approach; I believe you want

```
var result =   xDoc.Descendants("VHost")
                   .Descendants("ConnectionsTotal")
                   .Select(ele => ele.Value )
                   .Select( value => new clsApplication
                           {
                               ConnectionsTotal = value
                           })
                         ;
```

--- Test in LinqPad ---

```
string xml = @"
<Data>
<Server>
  <ConnectionsCurrent>67</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>1424182</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>1385091</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>39091</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>410455.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>540146.0</MessagesOutBytesRate> 
 </Server>
 <VHost>
  <Name>_defaultVHost_</Name> 
  <TimeRunning>5129615.178</TimeRunning> 
  <ConnectionsLimit>0</ConnectionsLimit> 
  <ConnectionsCurrent>67</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>1424182</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>1385091</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>39091</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>410455.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>540146.0</MessagesOutBytesRate> 
 </VHost>
 <Application>
  <Name>TestApp</Name> 
  <Status>loaded</Status> 
  <TimeRunning>411642.953</TimeRunning> 
  <ConnectionsCurrent>11</ConnectionsCurrent> 
  <ConnectionsTotal>43777</ConnectionsTotal> 
  <ConnectionsTotalAccepted>43135</ConnectionsTotalAccepted> 
  <ConnectionsTotalRejected>642</ConnectionsTotalRejected> 
  <MessagesInBytesRate>27876.0</MessagesInBytesRate> 
  <MessagesOutBytesRate>175053.0</MessagesOutBytesRate></Application>
  </Data>";


  var XDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

  XDoc.Descendants("VHost")
      .Descendants("ConnectionsTotal")
      .Select (ele => ele.Value )
      .Dump();
```

Comment: yes,exactly..but is there a way to avoid.element.element? That's why I'm trying to include the where clause so linq takes care

Comment: That gets all the connectionTotal's within the xml document. I just need to use the connectiontotals inside all the Applications