# Please help me with "a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause" in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `listbox` and a `datagridview`

Those MLB team list is from xml file I imported and what I have to do is

When I click the team on the list box it has to bring the player's name and hitting rate in the `datagridview` like the picture below

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    XElement BaseballXML = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Shinjo_PC\Desktop\EGR1400\Labs\Lab8\Baseball.xml");


public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    XElement BaseballXML = XElement.Load(@"C:\Users\Shinjo_PC\Desktop\EGR1400\Labs\Lab8\Baseball.xml");


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //pull all team from the list
        var ListTeams = from Baseball in BaseballXML.Descendants("player")
                    let team = Baseball.Element("team")
                    orderby team.Value
                    select team.Value;

        foreach (string teamname in ListTeams)
        {
            if (!lstTeams.Items.Contains(teamname))
            {
                lstTeams.Items.Add(teamname);
            }
        }
    }

    private void lstTeams_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var AverageQuery = from Players in BaseballXML.Descendants("player")
                        where Players.Element("team").Value == lstTeams.SelectedValue.ToString()
                        let atBats = double.Parse(Players.Element("atBats").Value)
                        let hits = double.Parse(Players.Element("hits").Value)
                        select new { hits, atBats };

        var myQuery = from bestbatter in BaseballXML.Descendants("player")
        dgvBaseball.DataSource = myQuery.ToList();
        dgvBaseball.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Player";
        dgvBaseball.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Batting Average";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting error at `dgvBaseball.DataSource = myQuery.ToList();`

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Have you had a look at this {SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13707388/linq-to-xml-a-query-body-must-end-with-a-select-clause-or-a-group-clause?rq=1) and the provided **Answer**?

Comment: Can you be more specific what your question is? Is it "I think my query meets the criteria but the error message says that it does not. Why not?" Or is it "Why must my query end with a select or groupby?" Or is it "How can I change query so it ends with a select or groupby?" Or something else?

Comment: at "dgvBaseball.DataSource = myQuery.ToList();" i'm getting "a query body must end with a select clause or a group clause” error message. how can i fix the problem? why do i see that error message?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the error message is as clear as it gets - your query is incomplete - it's missing the select or group by clause.

You need to add a select clause to this query:

```
var myQuery = from bestbatter in BaseballXML.Descendants("player")
              select bestbatter // This is the part you are missing....
```